# How to open and read file without buffering in C?

Tags: c, io

I want to benchmark an algorithm which operates on a file. The algorithm iterates N rounds and in each round, it reads one data block, do some magic stuff and set the offset of the next block.

Here's the pseudo code:

```
int run_algorithm(int offset) {

    char *fname = "database.dat";
    fd = open(fname, O_RDONLY);

    // read the desired block to memory
    block_size = 1024 * 1024;
    char *buf = malloc(block_size);
    lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, &buf, block_size);

    int new_offset;
    // do magic stuff with buf
    // and set a new offset

    close(fd);
    return new_offset;
}

int main() {

    int i;

    //init offset
    int offset = 0;

    // iterate N times
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        offset = run_algorithm(offset);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know the operating system has warm cache and cold cache. I want to implement the cold cache case. In each run_algorithm() call, there should be no buffering when the file is open. In other words, I don't want part of the file to be stored somewhere in the memory by the operating system to speed up the open() and seek().

Is there a way to specifically set the open() and seek() without buffering?

Comment: No, and even if you could tell the OS not to buffer you don't know if the drive controller or the onboard disk cache is affecting it

Comment: Are you on a Linux box?  If so, can you use `O_DIRECT` on the `open()` call?  That might reduce the amount of caching done by the system, at least during write operations.  But you're into sensitive areas and the system will go to extraordinary lengths to ensure that disk data is cached.

Comment: Why not open your file in `main` and pass a `FILE *fp` parameter to `run_algorithm` so you are not repeatedly opening/closing the file? You would move your `for` loop into `run_algorithm`, Also pass a pointer to an `int` (or address of an array) to `run_algorithm` and build an array of offsets and have `run_algorithm` return a pointer to the array (as well as being able to use the array passed as a pointer to the function.)

Answer (score 3):

You can't disable alll caches in the harddrive, and in the operating system.

But if you accept that you benchmark everything that's outside your program then you can disable buffering in the C run-time library:

```
setvbuf(fd, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

You must call the function immediatly after the fopen operation. See details in the [cpp reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf).